# Incompatible Types when when using a list of generic class in an interface

Tags: java, generics

I'm using java 1.8 and I get this incompatibility error.

```
public interface AVCR<T extends ACRI> {
    List<CRTIL<T>> getLists();
}

public class CRTIL<T extends ACRI> {
}

class BV {
    public AVCR<? extends ACRI> getDeafult() {
       return;
    }

    public List<CRTIL<? extends ACRI>>
        getTypeLists() {
        return getDefault().getLists();
        //Incompatible types
    }

}
```

The compiler error:
found

```
List<? extends CRTIL<? extends ACRI>>
```

and requires

```
List<CRTIL<? extends ACRI>>
```

Comment: This code doesn't compile.

Comment: updated post with error

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your question correctly as you do not provide a minimal working example but I try:

You could change the method signature of `getTypeLists` as follows

```
public List<? extends CRTIL<? extends ACRI>> getTypeLists()
```

since you are returning a list of type `? extends CRTIL<? extends ACRI>` and not of type `CRTIL<? extends ACRI>`.